# Kafka consumer unique cluster ID?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Does a Kafka cluster have some unique ID that I can get programmatically out of a Kafka consumer? I checked for message headers, but it looks like there's no metadata in them by default and I don't see any methods in a `KafkaConsumer` or `ConsumerRecord` for retrieving such a value either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AdminClient to get the cluster id, but generally, there's no reason for clients to know internal server information

Comment: We need to compute increasing sequence numbers for each message. We store a triple (cluster, offset, seq) in a DB after each processed message. If we notice a cluster change or see a lower offset, then we need to do a more expensive query to figure out the next sequence number before the consumer can continue.

Comment: The Kafka cluster ID should not change while it is active and healthy, and offsets for a topic cannot decrease